# Rails4: image_url not generating digest in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, sprockets

I have this code:

```ruby
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = { status: "ok", message: "Success!", image_url: image_url('image.png') }
      format.json  { render :json => msg }
    end
  end
end
```

This return me this response:

```
{ status: "ok", message: "Success!", image_url: 'images/image.png' }
```

And I expect something like:

```
{ status: "ok", message: "Success!", image_url: 'assets/image-37bf76be1.png' }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: If your current Rails environment is not production, this is completely normal.

Comment: My environment is development, but when I request `http://localhost:3000/images/image.png` it returns 404. When I use "image_url" inside rails view it works correctly and add digest hash. Why it don't works in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use `view_context.image_url` if you want to render an image from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As born4new suggested, you'll need to use `image_url` to properly reference the image from the asset pipeline. **However, I wouldn't recommend using the asset pipeline here.** Keep in mind that your asset digest URL can change when you precompile your assets. Since you're serving this value from an API, this means that you're responding with a URL that will likely render a 404 once you recompile assets.

Instead, you should consider serving your image as a static asset from the `public/` folder. This way, any consumers of your API can access these files reliably after you redeploy or regenerate your assets.

Comment: Thaks this is a good solution if you don't have caching problem.